Is it possible to use registers on Intel‑based FPGAs ? If not what’s the alternative for solving the bandwidth issue?
In order to bruteforce a key where the first private’s key bytes are known (leaving 270 possible private key to search) I’d like to do the following:

pick up a 64‑bit private key range

split that range for each so called kernel

still on the host, generate public keys for each kernel

Then on each so called kernel:

generate sha1(from the 256‑bits bits public key as an integer value)
A part of the problem is here as of course it’s possible to split each round for pipelining but that requires storing each intermediate value from each round separately instead of reusing a register

If the first 64‑bit equal a specific hardcoded value

if true set a global boolean value from 0 to 1

If not, perform a Koblitz’s curve point addition on the public key by G and try again.
That step can also be pipelined if using multiplication at a cost greater than addition






A similar solution on a H100 GPU using CUDA allows to generate and test 4 billion keys per second. The problem is using memory instead of registers would mean the bandwidth would cripple the speed: a typical FPGA uses DDR3/DDR4 built‑in memory controllers and I’m looking to achieve a performance per watt better than a high‑end GPU by being faster.
I also need to do it on cloud/rented FPGA. I have never heard of a cloud provider offering to rent an FPGA connected to GDDR memory instead of regular DDR memory.
As testing a key doesn’t require that much memory (as shown by Bitcoin miners which used FPGA before ASICs to get better performance than a GPU) is it acceptable in terms of performance to create registers on the target high‑end FPGA for having fast enough memory?
If yes, what’s the tradeoff to take between increasing pipelining level and decreasing the number of registers requirements?
If not, how to solve such bandwidth problem using high‑end FPGA hardware that can be rented either physically or in the cloud?

Intel Agilex® 7 FPGA M-Series 039 Features hbm2 memory but it seems hard to find a provider renting boards.

Intel and AMD FPGAs are predominantly RAM based. Each LUT is a small but very fast SRAM (sub 1 ns r/w time). This is the basis for the programmable logic - you can map any logic function into the Look Up Table. These LUTs feed into a ‘real’ register. This is your basic Lego building block for a FPGA. Depending on the size of the FPGA is how many of these blocks are available. In addition you have blockram which is a configurable block of high speed SRAM usually with registers and dual port access. So for your internal computation, you’d most likely be using these resources. The external DDR is for your bulk data storage.
How it is all configured is up to you and the amount of resources available in the FPGA.
Anywhere from small and slow serial 1 bit per clock or as parallel as you can fit.
You can do tricks like reading a block of data from DDR RAM in parallel with your computations into high speed block ram and doing the next batch of computations whilst writing the previous results back to DDR RAM.
How do you know what you can fit into a given FPGA? With experience you can guesstimate what resources are needed but usually it is ‘suck it and see’ - write a module and see what it consumes. If you use ‘off the shelf IP’ that will have the required information as part of the package.

Maybe add the width of the flipflop register in the logic slices. That way one can at least obtain an order of magnitude of available SRAM

@Kartman I don t need low latency but high bandwidth. This is 2 different things (gpu memory typically achieves higher bandwidth by increasing latency).

I think you need to concentrate more on the ‘system bandwidth’ - no use having the world’s fastest memory if the computation hardware can’t keep up. Also note that pipelining uses registers and we’re talking about registers in a hardware flip/flop context as opposed to a cpu register. Registers in a cpu would probably be ram these days. As for the tradeoff between pipelining and ‘registers’ - that’s an implementation detail. High end fpgas have dsp slices that will do fast multiplies and other ops. You have to break down your algorithm into basic ops, calc the timing of each then implement.

sha1 from 256bits is fully pipelinable so I don t think system speed will be a problem. Intel fpga m have hbm2 memory but do you know a cloud provider renting them?

Sha1 is probably the least of the challenges you face. Unless you have hard evidence to determine what bandwidth you can actually use, going down the bandwidth path is premature optimisation. Unless you have an implementation, you can’t simulate so it’s all pretty much a guess. As well, asking for product recommendations is off topic here.
